# how to perform Histogram equalisation in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy, histogram

I am trying to equalise the histogram of an image I want to perform further processing on. The code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image2.jpg', 0)
equ = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
res = np.hstack((img, equ)) # stacking images side-by-side
cv2.imwrite('res.png', res)
```

I got this code online, but I can't see anything wrong with it. The problem is when I run the code I get a very small black box on a white background, instead of my original image with better contrast. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me, using cv2 version 2.4.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet works totally fine for me (OpenCV 2.3.1): I get a double-sized output image with the original on the left and an histogram-equalized version on the right.

You may want to check another source of mistake (wrong files, wrong directory, etc...).

Comment: I ran the code again after restarting my pc and it works just fine, thank you.